# N-ary tree structure modeling in DDB

Tags: graph, amazon-dynamodb, hierarchical-data, amazon-dynamodb-index, hierarchical-query

I have requirement to model hierarchical questionnaire in DDB. The questionnaire will be stored in Dynamo DB, and users will access these questionnaires. Based on the input provided by the user, a score will be calculated.

**Questions Details:**

1. Each question can have multiple options.
2. While the table below does not explicitly depict it, each option may lead to next question, and a single question set can have a variable number of questions.

**Question Set and Score calculation details: following table explains the dependency of questions and score calculation mechanism**

|  | Q1 | Q2 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QuestionSet 1 | Do you own car?[options: (yes, no)] | Yes: When was the last service? [options: (greater than 1 months, greater that 4 months)] | No=20, greater than one month=15 greater than four month=5 |
| QuestionSet 2 | Do you like travel?[options: (yes, no)] | Yes: Where did you travel recently? [multi choice options: 1) New York = 5 , 2) California = 4, 3) Seattle = 7))] | no = 20, yes : total sum of second question option |

I am planning to structure each question set as n-ary tree. Where node will be connected by question's options value. See following image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBcSO.png)

Looking for following details:

1. How can I model the questions in Dynamo DB.
2. How can I model the user's response so that score can be calculated.